# Preventing relative require calls from modules in a specific folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

This will sound odd, but I'd like all modules in a specific directory to only be able to require resources out of node_modules and not from any other part of the application.

In a specific directory:

- `require('fs')` -- should work
- `require('../../something')` -- denied
- `require('./another')` -- denied

Is anything like this remotely possible in Node?

Comment: This seems like an odd thing to do, but if you can explain your rationale then someone might be able to suggest something better.  If you're running untrusted code, then `require` is the least of your worries...

Comment: Definitely odd.  An argument was deployed against internalizing some modules because "people might make relative require calls" (thus creating speghettified code rather than independent modules).  And while I think it makes organizational/application sense to move them there, the other party is concerned about devs doing stupid things.  It's not the code that's untrusted, it's the developers writing it, apparently.

Comment: Could you make a pre-receive hook (in your vcs) that searches for something like `/require\('\.*/g` and rejects the commit (with a helpful message) if it finds it? This way, you can still enforce this rule without making node continuously work to enforce it.

Comment: @MichaelTang A solid recommendation.  I will definitely look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a module that'll act like a require-proxy:

```
module.exports.require2 = function() {
    if (arguments[0][0] !== '.') {
        return require.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        throw new Error('Can\'t require relative modules');
    }
}
```

Of course, this would be opt-in by the developers:

```
var require2 = require('require2');
var fs = require2('fs'); //everything's good
var fss = require2('./fss'); //throws an error
```

Kind of a similar idea to thlorenz's [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire).